# Update Claim value in User Claims list whenever it is changed in Database

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using IdentityServer4 Implicit flow for my Angular application. I have permissions claim added to scope list and also it gets populated properly. 
i need to update this claim value whenever i change the value in database.

currently, the claim value is refreshed only when access_token is refreshed/renewed.

I want to check/update claims on every call to api.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. You are mixing authentication with authorization. The permission claims should not be present in the Access token. Please [read here](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/) why. And read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079466/is-claims-based-authorization-appropriate-for-individual-resources/52100609#52100609) for some thoughts about a possible design.
2. You can't change a JWT.

> An access token contains information about the client and the user (if
>   present). It is a self-contained code that can be decoded by the
>   server only and has a certain lifetime.

Please note that the refresh token does not really refresh the access token, it creates a new token. The original token remains valid until it expires. An alternative is to use [Reference Tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/reference_tokens.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the links you have shared. 

actually, im using Reference Token and I'm getting the Claims from UserInforEnd points. 

Requirement ;
User A has certain access rights (Read, Write, Delete). User logs in, gets his permissions (as a permission Claim value - Not recommended i guess but I'm using it for my scenario - I'm using IdentityServer as 
 Authorization Server).
 Now If an administration removes his Delete permission, the claims are not updated until the token is expired the application gets a new access_token for the current user session.

Comment: currently I achieved this requirement by using IPersistedGrantService (RemoveAllGrantsAsync(SubjectId, ClientId) to revoke user access_token. whenever an admin changes a user claims RemoveAllGrantsAsync(SubjectId, ClientId) is called to revoke his access_token.

Comment: As an alternative, regardless of the kind of token, you can set the token expiration to a short period, like 5 minutes. In that case the changes become effective within 5 minutes, without having to revoke tokens. If the flow allows it, use refresh tokens for a good user experience.

Comment: And about IdentityServer, it is not for authorization, but authentication. **Who** is the user (identity)? Hence the name. It is not about authorization: **What** is the user allowed to do. Also, this is not what the UserInfoEndpoint is for. It should be used to request additional information about _who_ the user is.

Comment: If you create your own (authorization) API to retrieve authorization (making it independent from IdentityServer) then you are half way. Instead of calling the UserInfoEndpoint call your own authorization endpoint.