# IdentityServer for applications that are mulitenant database

Tags: identityserver4

I have 2 software with different business logic,different database, both are multi tenant, every user has the TenantId property to identify the data of their organization

```
dbo.Xpto.Where(x => x.TenantId == userLogged.TenantId);
```

I am wanting to unify the login and implement `identityserver`, I have the doubt, how will I capture the user `tenantId` if it has different `tenantId` in each software?

I thought of adding claims, for example new `Claim ("SoftwareOne:TenantId", 123)` and `new Claim ("SoftwareTwo:TenantId", "8f8b8d87-fc07-4508-a33a-2b5f55820836")` and request by `Scope`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to see *authentication* seperated from *authorization*.

Use IdentityServer to *authenticate* and in general authorize (and by that I mean without context specific claims) the user. While the actual *authorization* is done locally or by a seperate authorization server.

*My setup would be like this:*

- *Identity context*: users + userclaims. For authentication only. *Context independent*, e.g. As a freelance consultant I have a specific role in different organizations, while my profession remains the same.

  So the *profession* claim would be a UserClaim, while *Role* would be an authorization claim.
- *Authorization context*: users (id = sub claim) + per application: roles, permissions, etc. In seperate 'local' databases or in a central database. *Context specific*, for authorization only. Take a look at [PolicyServer](http://policyserver.io/).

  Instead of or combined with an authorization server you can implement [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).
- *Business context*: users (Id, Name, 'foreign key' sub claim, without the actual database relation as the table is outside the context) + teams, profile, settings, etc. Linked to the sub claim value when users table is omitted.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079466/is-claims-based-authorization-appropriate-for-individual-resources/52100609#52100609) for additional information.

Comment: Thanks again @Ruard . But what I do not understand is where and how will I store the TenantId in runtime to query the data in DbContext (Global Filter)

Your authorizing suggestion I do not understand, will I have to have an authorization for each tenant and asign the authorization with all users of this tenant?

Comment: Instead of IdentityServer let the PolicyServer add claims to the Identity. If you take a look at the source (PolicyServer.Local), then you'll see that in middleware an identity and claims are added. But you also can think of another approach where tenantid is part of the User in the business context. In that case you don't need claims.

Comment: Hi, Ruard. Unfortunately the PolicyServer is a paid product(My company and team is small). Your suggestion to leave TenantId as Idsrv's own context is easy
it is easy migrate a single key to guid (my example above) than to keep an authorization server

Comment: The local version is opensource: https://github.com/policyserver/policyserver.local