# How to use UserClaims for Tenant authority applications?

Tags: claims-based-identity, claims, claims-authentication

Currently I am working on a project that will have departments managers and users separated by abilities/roles/claims.

I will use the claims-based authorization to accomplish this but I'm having trouble with departments have encapsulated claims

A IT and HR department can create/add a user not only to their respective departments but to other departments.  The clerks and sales department admin can only add users to their department.

- I don't think this is the best way of handling the UserClaims

```
IT.CanAddUser
IT.CanAddITUser
HR.CanAddUser
HR.CannAddHRUser
Sales.CanAddSalesUser
Clerks.CanAddClerkUser
```

- I aslo don't think this works because every department have to create a CanAdd[Dept]User.

```
CanAddSalesUser
CanAddClerkUser
CanAddITUser
```

- I also don't think this is the best way of handling the UserClaims

```
SuperAdmin
IT.UserAdmin
IT.CanAddUser
HR.UserAdmin
HR.CanAddUser
Sales.CanAddUser
Clerks.CanAddUser
```

because UserAdmin is still tied to the IT and HR departments so another xxx.UserAdmin

- I also don't think adding another column to the UserClaims table will help

```
Id
UserId
DepartmentId
ClaimType 
ClaimValue
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079466/is-claims-based-authorization-appropriate-for-individual-resources/52100609#52100609)

Comment: @RuardvanElburg So from what I read I should create a PermissionsContext with the following table:

`
UserPermTable
UserID
Permission
`

Comment: Yes, it maps one or more permissions to a user (which is identified by a claim, e.g. sub, id, userid). Though I would use additional tables. E.g. AuthUser for Id, UserId so you can relate tables to the Id field: UserPermTable.AuthUserId. No need to repeat the claim value in all tables and use int Id instead. In case you want to remove a user, you can simply clear the UserId claim in the AuthUser table. And you can configure multi-level authorization, e.g. a role contains permissions.