# Separate Identity Server 4 database from application database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I have an existing SQL database containing my user data and application data. I want to implement Identity Server 4 in such a way that its tables are in a separate database from the application database. I don't want Identity server 4 tables in my current database. How do I go about this? If anyone has links to guidelines on how to achieve this, I would be grateful.

My current db was created by asp.net boilerplate and now am using asp.net zero

Comment: I can't give you the technical details on how to implement this, but I can share [some thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079466/is-claims-based-authorization-appropriate-for-individual-resources/52100609#52100609) about how to setup seperate contexts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ef core, you just need to provide different dbcontext for your user data. 
Identityserver4 have extension called **AddAspNetIdentity** to use ASP Net Identity
You can refer here for the docs
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/aspnet_identity.html

you can refer to their sample here
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity

Answer (score 0):

You can persist IdentityServer configurations in separated databases.

[Using EntityFramework Core for configuration and operational data](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_entityframework.html)